# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a simple web application and keep getting this error.

```
app.get("/campground/:id/comments/new",function(req,res){
    camp.findById(req.params.id)({
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else        
            res.render("comments/new",{campground:camp});
    });
});
```

and keep getting this error

```
 console.log(err);
 ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

If I remove error Handling,I get the error,

```
res.render("comments/new",{campground:camp});
   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Can Anyone Help?

Comment: How do you run your script? Is there some funky stuff before it calls `node thescript.js`?

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger! Luckily, this is your chance to learn the Greatest Skill You Will Ever Learn: Debugging! https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `findById` properly, it should have a callback function, something like this:

```
app.get("/campground/:id/comments/new",function(req, res, err){
    camp.findById(req.params.id, function(err, camp) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {   
            res.render("comments/new",{campground:camp});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `findById` is likely Mongoose method (the question says nothing about that), and the callback certainly doesn't have to have `(req, res, err)` signature, this shadows params from parent function.

Comment: @estus You're right, I'll edit the params in my answer.